# Failed to execute command line argument from python script

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to run a command line argument through python script. Script triggers the .exe but it throws an error as `System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.`.
Following is my code :

```
import os , sys , os.path
from subprocess import call
import subprocess, shlex
def execute(cmd):
    """
        Purpose  : To execute a command and return exit status
    """
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (result, error) = process.communicate()

    rc = process.wait()

    if rc != 0:
        print "Error: failed to execute command:",cmd
        print error
    return result

found_alf = r"C:\AniteSAS\ResultData\20170515\Run01\1733200515.alf"
filter_alvf = r"C:\Users\sshaique\Desktop\ALF\AniteLogFilter.alvf"

command = str(r'ALVConsole.exe -e -t -i ' + '\"'+found_alf+'\"' + ' --ffile ' + '\"'+filter_alvf+'\"')
print command
os.chdir('C:\Program Files\Anite\LogViewer\ALV2')
print os.getcwd()
print "This process detail: \n", execute(command)
```

Output is as follows :

> ALVConsole.exe -e -t -i "C:\AniteSAS\ResultData\20170515\Run01\1733200515.alf" --ffile "C:\Users\sshaique\Desktop\ALF\AniteLogFilter.alvf"
>   C:\Program Files\Anite\LogViewer\ALV2
>
> This process detail: 
>   Error: failed to execute command: ALVConsole.exe -e -t -i "C:\AniteSAS\ResultData\20170515\Run01\1733200515.alf" --ffile "C:\Users\sshaique\Desktop\ALF\AniteLogFilter.alvf"
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>
> at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
>
> at ALV.Console.CommandLineParametersHandler.ConsoleWriteLine(String message, Boolean isError)
>
> at ALV.Console.CommandLineParametersHandler.InvokeActions()
>
> at ALV.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)

When I copy the command line argument from the above output and run manually from cmd it works fine.
`ALVConsole.exe -e -t -i "C:\AniteSAS\ResultData\20170515\Run01\1733200515.alf" --ffile "C:\Users\sshaique\Desktop\ALF\AniteLogFilter.alvf"`

I am using Windows 7 and Python 2.7.13 for. Please suggest overcoming this issue.

**EDIT:** 
I have also tried to pass command as a list `s` as per below code but the issue remains the same.

```
command = str(r'ALVConsole.exe -e --csv -i ' + '\"'+found_alf+'\"' + ' --ffile ' + '\"'+filter_alvf+'\"')
s=shlex.split(command)
print s
print "This process detail: \n", execute(s)
```

Comment: Why are you passing the entire command as a single string instead of a list?

Comment: Why it should be a problem ?@cricket_007

Comment: Maybe because of the way python passes arguments to commands

Comment: I am uncomfortable in doing this with a list , could you please suggest?@cricket_007

Comment: What is so uncomfortable about `['ALVConsole.exe', '-e',...]`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I did as follows :`cmd_list=[]
cmd_list.extend(['ALVConsole.exe',' -e --csv -i ','\"',found_alf,'\"',' --ffile ','\"',filter_alvf,'\"'])
print cmd_list
s=''.join(cmd_list)` and call(s) but same issue .

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question to include additional information

Comment: Don't join the list... Read the documentation on `subprocess.Popen` please

Comment: And why did you make `'\"'` it's own argument?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried passing the command as the list and issue are same. I need to have a double quote in those positions.

Comment: Do you need quotes? There are no spaces in your filepaths... My point was that the quotes need to be *part of the filename*, not a *separate argument. Keep the pluses there, don't use commas to concatenate strings. `['ALVConsole.exe', '-e', '-t', '-i', r'"{}"'.format(found_alf), '--ffile', r'"{}"'.format(ilter_alvf)]`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error messages I think that this problem is with ALVConsole.exe, not your Python script.

When you redirect the output, ALVConsole.exe tries to do something to the console (like setting cursor position, or getting the size of the terminal) but fails like this.

Is there a flag to ALVConsole.exe that modifies the output to a machine-readable version? I wasn't able to find the documentation for this program.

Comment: I am not sure how ALVconsole.exe will work.It is a part of a network logging tool and you will not find any documentations for this as it is for our internal purpose only.

Comment: I understand, so maybe you have access to the source code and can fix it. It looks like a bug to me. The error is from that program, not from Python, at least.